# what does ≼ or ≺ mean?

Tags: notation, order-theory

I was reading a paper about well-orderings and this came up:

Suppose (E, ≤) and (F, ≼) are isomorphic well-orderings. Then there exists a unique isomorphism for (E, ≤) to (F, ≼).

I've been scouring the internet for what this symbol means. Someone said it means "precedes", but that led me to wonder if 1 ≼ 2 would be true but then someone else said that X ≼ Y <=> $$X = X\land Y$$ which made no sense to me. Could someone explain the meaning of this symbol? Thanks.

Comment: I think they just want to make it clear that $\leq$ is not the same ordering as  ≼

Comment: $\preceq$ is just some ordering on $F$, in this case a well-ordering.

Comment: I think it's probably just notation to distinguish the ordering on $F$ from that on $E$. Other acceptable symbols include $\preceq$, $\sqsubseteq$, etc.

Comment: To explain what they mean by $X\preceq Y\Leftrightarrow X=X\wedge Y$, they are referring to the [Meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet) of $X$ and $Y$.  You have $x\wedge y=z\Leftrightarrow z\preceq x$ and $z\preceq y$.  In the case that $z=x$ and $z=x\wedge y$, that implies that $x\preceq y$

Answer (score 8):

In this context, "$\le$" and "$\preccurlyeq$" are just names for binary relations on $E$ and $F$. Since these relations are orderings, we use suggestive symbols; but that's all. For instance, maybe $E=\{1, 3, 172\}$ and $\preccurlyeq$ is the relation $\{(1, 3), (172, 1), (172, 3), (172, 172), (1, 1), (3, 3)\}$ - that is, $172\preccurlyeq 1\preccurlyeq 3$. This would be perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes more sense than anything else I have found.

Comment: How is 172≼1≼3? Wouldn't it be 172≽1≽3 (I'm assuming ≽ means comes after) since 172 comes after 3 and 1? Or am I wrong, if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: @TheSpanglock "$\preccurlyeq$" is represented by (or is) the set of ordered pairs $(a, b)$ such that $a\preccurlyeq b$. So e.g. $(1, 3)\in\preccurlyeq$ means that $1\preccurlyeq 3$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thanks.

Comment: So then would 172 ≼ 1 for (172, 1) $$\in ≼$$

Comment: Yes, since $(172, 1)$ is in $\preccurlyeq$. (Also I just noticed I used "$\le$" instead of "$\preccurlyeq$" once; fixed.)

Comment: Thanks. I thought ≼ had a meaning like ≤ does, with "greater than or equal to". I thought there was an absolute definition on it.

Comment: So  if  172 ≼ 1,  then is 172 ≽ 1  true? Or  is  it false  since  $$(172, 1) \in ≼ \land (172, 1) \notin ≽$$

Comment: Usually we use "$\succcurlyeq$" to denote the converse of "$\preccurlyeq$" (or vice versa, depending which one was defined first) - so since $(172, 1)\in\preccurlyeq$, that would mean $(1, 172)\in\succcurlyeq$. But again this is just convention (albeit a pretty universal one).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I just have one last question, and I apologise if I'm asking too many, but if we had a set (E, ≤) with E still being the same, would 1 ≤ 3 since $$(1,3) \in ≤$$ Or would that be false since it goes against the definition of ≤.

Answer (score 7):

The curly versions of the less than and greater than signs are commonly used to denote some other ordering than the one that we are usually talking about. For instance there is a partial ordering on the symmetric matrices, where $A \preccurlyeq B$ if and only if $B-A$ is a nonnegative definite matrix. We write $\preccurlyeq$ instead of $\leq$ to avoid confusion with the ordering that we use more commonly. This would be especially important if we had two orderings on the same set.

But it's just a symbol. It would be perhaps confusing but certainly not wrong to use it some other way.